# How can i set a maximum amount for a payment application in android

Tags: android

I want to put a limit to the amount of payment they can process on the application like 4,999.99. so the limit is 1.00 to 4,999.99 how do i set the application to block from inputing an amount more than that?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information if you want some help. Where do you want the limit to apply? Is it in the UI or in the business logic? If in the UI, what component are you using to capture input?

Comment: i am using an EditText for the input and i want to set the limit on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you areusing `EditText` for user's input.

Add `textChangeListener` on your `EditText` andcheck what the user's input. If the input is not in the desired range than show an error message.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      // put your check here
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to answer above, don't forget to set inputType to edittext

```
android:inputType:"numberDecimal"
```